# How can I increase a GLatLngBounds (rectangle) by 10% in google maps API?

Tags: math, google-maps, coordinates

I have a map with a bunch of points on it, and I want to zoom such that all points fit on the screen. The code for this is fairly simple:

```
var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();

for (var n = 0; n < points.length; n++) {
  bounds.extend(points[n].getLatLng());
}

zoomLevel = map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds);
```

to get the zoom level, you have to pass in a bounds object. To create a bounds object, you either give it two points like a rectangle, or you pass it a point and it increases in size (if necessary) to incorporate the point which is what I do above.

The problem is that the points appear right on the edge of the screen. I'd like to increase the size of the bounds by say, 10%. I can get the two points out of my bounds object using `bounds.getNorthEast();` and `bounds.getSouthWest();` but to increase them by 10% of the size of the bounds is proving tricky. I tried `toSpan()` on the bounds which gives you a LatLng containing the size of the bounds, and then did 10% of the Lat and Lng and added it to my coordinates. However, it did not seem to work. My code for this attempt was:

```
var pointNorthEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
var pointSouthWest = bounds.getSouthWest();

var latAdjustment = ((pointNorthEast.lat() - pointSouthWest.lat()) * increasePercentage) / 2;
var lngAdjustment = ((pointNorthEast.lng() - pointSouthWest.lng()) * increasePercentage) / 2;


var newPointNorthEast = new GLatLng(pointNorthEast.lat() + latAdjustment, pointNorthEast.lng() + lngAdjustment);
var newPointSouthWest = new GLatLng(pointSouthWest.lat() - latAdjustment, pointSouthWest.lng() - lngAdjustment);


bounds = new GLatLngBounds();

bounds.extend(newPointNorthEast);
bounds.extend(newPointSouthWest);
```

By my reckoning, bounds should then be 10% bigger. I'm not certain it represents just a rectangle or stores any coordinate data or not so I didn't take chances by adding/subtracting half of the increase on each side to keep it centered.

However, trying various increasePercentage values such as 1.1 or 1.5 it does not seem to make a difference.

Therefore I've either cocked up my logic, my maths, or the fact that zoomLevel is not a smooth scale is hampering my attempts.

I think I might have to just do `zoomLevel -= 1` and have done with it, but I wanted to see if anyone had any ideas first.

Comment: It was 3 years ago, I can't even remember what I had for dinner last night...

Comment: That's what I thought but I asked just in case :P

Answer (score 3):

here's updated code using current api version (v3.0):

```
var increasePercentage = 1.10;  //10%
var pointSouthWest = mb.getSouthWest();
var latAdjustment = (pointNorthEast.lat() - pointSouthWest.lat()) * (increasePercentage - 1);
var lngAdjustment = (pointNorthEast.lng() - pointSouthWest.lng()) * (increasePercentage - 1);
var newPointNorthEast = new google.maps.LatLng(pointNorthEast.lat() + latAdjustment, pointNorthEast.lng() + lngAdjustment);
var newPointSouthWest = new google.maps.LatLng(pointSouthWest.lat() - latAdjustment, pointSouthWest.lng() - lngAdjustment);

bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(newPointNorthEast);
bounds.extend(newPointSouthWest);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your Math, here's how you need to calculate adjustments:

```
var latAdjustment = ((pointNorthEast.lat() - pointSouthWest.lat()) * (increasePercentage - 1);
var lngAdjustment = ((pointNorthEast.lng() - pointSouthWest.lng()) * (increasePercentage - 1);
```